# CDI Injection not possible in a JAX-RS subresource instance created by ResourceContext initResource

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a JAX-RS resource class that provides path routing to sub resource classes using @Context ResourceContext to create sub resource instances for each resource type. In this example I am instantiating a reporting sub resource.

**Resource**

```
@Context
ResourceContext rc;

@Path("reports")
public ReportsResource reportsResource() {
    return rc.initResource(new ReportsResource());
}
```

The sub resource needs an instance of a ReportService class (defined with the @Stateless annotation), the natural solution would be to @Inject it ...

**Report SubResource**

```
@Inject
ReportsService rs;

@GET
@Path("{rptno}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Report report(@PathParam("rptno") int rptNumber) throws Exception {
    return rs.getReport(rptNumber);
}
```

My experience using Java EE7 with both Glassfish and WAS Liberty Profile 
is that an instance of ReportService rs is not injected, leaving rs as null and causing a NPE.

My assumption is that because the resource class is doing a "new ReportsResource()", CDI has no visibility to the ReportsResource instance and so ReportsResource is not container managed.
This seems to be the same situation as this question [Inject EJB into JAX-RS 2.0 subresource when subresource is got via ResourceContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682505/inject-ejb-into-jax-rs-2-0-subresource-when-subresource-is-got-via-resourceconte)

My solution is somewhat different, I chose to @Inject ReportService in the Resource class, then pass the instance on the ReportsResource constructor.

**Modified Resource**

```
@Inject
ReportsSerivce rs;

@Context
ResourceContext rc;

@Path("reports")
public ReportsResource reportsResource() {
    return rc.initResource(new ReportsResource(rs));
}
```

**Modified Report Subresource**

```
public class ReportsResource {
    private ReportsSerivce rs;

    public ReportsResource(ReportsSerivce rs) {
      this.rs = rs;
    }

    @Context
    HttpHeaders headers;

    @GET
    @Path("{rptno}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Report report(@PathParam("rptno") int rptNumber) throws Exception {
        return rs.getReport(rptNumber);
    }
```

So to my questions

1. Is my assumption about why @Inject fails correct?
2. Is there any way to make @Inject work in the sub resource?
3. Is there a better solution to passing the ReportService instance from Resource to SubResource that is more "CDI/Java EE" like?

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122079/cdi-injection-not-possible-in-a-jax-rs-subresource-instance-created-by-resourcec/53594433#53594433

Answer (score 8):

If you want to inject CDI beans into JAX-RS resources, I don't recommend using [rc.initResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html#initResource-T-). All it does is injection of fields into existing object, but it uses JAX-RS specific mechanism, similar to how injection worked for EJBs in JavaEE5, when CDI was not available.

It is better to use CDI and remove `ResourceContext` from your code.

Example:

**Resource**

```
@Inject
private ReportsResource reportsResource;

@Path("reports")
public ReportsResource reportsResource() {
    return reportsResource;
}
```

The master resource should be `@RequestScoped` so that it gets recreated for each request. Or you may inject using [Intance](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html) to get new instance for every method call:

```
@Inject
private Instance<ReportsResource> reportsResources;

@Path("reports")
public ReportsResource reportsResource() {
    return reportsResources.get();
}
```

Comment: The problem I see with using @Inject with the ReportsResource is that this class is front end resource for many sub resources. It would have to create an instance of every possible sub resource class for every request, whereas if the new is done in the method for each sub resource, only the class required to satisfy the request is instantiated.

Comment: The point is that in JavaEE you don't need to use JAX-RS specific `ResourceContext.initResource` and you may initiate the resource by CDI injection. I don't see what you mean as you may use `reportsResources.get()` from my second example instead of `new` and it only creates the instance for that particular method call - the same thing as `new` but with dependencies injected.

Comment: I know that using `Instance` to create the resource dynamically is not very intuitive, it would be better if injection as method parameter worked, but CDI currently does not support it. I mean this would be nicer but does not work (yet in Java EE 7): `public ReportsResource reportsResource(@Inject ReportsResource rr) { return rr;}`

Comment: I may be mistaken, I was under the impression that
@Inject
private ReportsResource reportsResource;
Created an instance of ReportsResource, therefore if I used this method for every class a sub resource might need an instance of, then there would be a lot of unused instances for the sub resources I am not calling for this request.

Comment: CDI creates an instance of `ReportsResource` for each injection point ONLY when injected directly (without `Instance`) AND `ReportsResource` has `@Dependent` scope, which is default. If you change the scope to something else, e.g. `@RequestScoped`, a single instance will be reused for all injection points during processing of a request, and it will be created the first time you call a method on an injected instance. Until that point, only an empty proxy is injected. If using `Instance` and `get()`, creation of an instance is fully under your control, but again, scoped instances will be reused.

Comment: I get an error: `linkeddatahub_1     | 10-Oct-2020 00:46:18.119 WARNING [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-1] org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.logErrors The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
linkeddatahub_1     | MultiException stack 1 of 3
linkeddatahub_1     | org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ProxyResourceBase,parent=ResourceBase,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1215401275)`

Answer (score 2):

Note that injecting the sub resource directly into the root resource may cause a problem. I'm sharing what I've learnt.

```
@Path("parents")
class ParentsResource {

    @Path("/{parentId: \\d+}/{children: children}");
    public ChildrenResource resourceChildren() {
        return childrenResource;
    }

    @Inject
    private ChildrenResource childrenResource;
}

class ChildrenResource {

    @PostConstruct
    private void onPostConstruct() {
        parentName = children.getMatrixParameters().getFirst("parentName");
    }

    @PathParam("children");
    private PathSegment children; // may or may not be null

    private String parentName;
}
```

Following works.

```
/parents/1/children
/parents/1/children;parentName=Kwon
```

And we might got a `NullPointerException` when we simple call

```
/parents
/parents/1
```

Because the injection of the `ChildrenResource` instance itself happens before it injected into the `ParentResource`.

In this case, `Optional` might help

```
parentName = ofNullable(children)
        .map(v -> v.getMatrixParameters().getFirst("parentName")
        .orElse(null);
```

But using `ResourceContext` can be said more proper.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of Jersey (JAX-RS reference implementation) if you want your sub-resource's lifecycle to be managed by container, you have to return the class type and not an instance of it. You can then manage the lifecycle of sub-resource as you wish like any other container managed resource.

For example:

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Path("/item")
public class ItemResource {
    @Path("content")
    public Class<ItemContentSingletonResource> getItemContentResource() {
        return ItemContentSingletonResource.class;
    }
}

@Singleton
public class ItemContentSingletonResource {
    // this class is managed in the singleton life cycle
}
```

more info could be found on docs: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2496

Comment: I'm not sure if thats part of the standard or not, but due to the fact that Jersey is the reference implementation of JAX-RS, I would say RESTEasy has earned a bug report here!

Comment: That link is broken. New link to Jersey documentation ("Chapter 3. JAX-RS Application, Resources and Sub-Resources"): https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2641

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

**Resource**

```
@Path("reports")
public ReportsResource reportsResource() {
    return CDI.current().select(ReportsResource.class).get();
}
```

**Subresource**

```
@Inject ReportBean reportBean;

@GET
@Path("/{rptno}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Report report(@PathParam("rptno") int rptNumber) throws Exception {
    return reportBean.getReport(rptNumber);
}
```